# I can't get Git to use Vim IN THE DOS SHELL -- it says "cannot run sh"

Tags: git, vim

I want Git to use Vim.  I'm not new to this, at least on Unix, where it's really easy.  But as with anything in DOS, it seems a pointless struggle.  I think I'm probably missing something obvious.

So I did this:

```
>git config --global core.editor "\"c:\Program Files\Vim\vim71\gvim.exe\""
```

But this happens:

```
> C:\dev\qfnet\quickfix.net>git commit -a
"c:\Program Files\Vim\vim71\gvim.exe": c:\Program Files\Vim\vim71\gvim.exe: command not found
error: cannot run sh: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '"c:\Program Files\Vim\vim71\gvim.exe"'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I also tried setting the EDITOR variable, with similar results.

"sh" is in my path so I don't know why it can't find it.  If I run "sh" from the prompt, it does start correctly, as far as I can tell.  (What's it trying to run "sh" for anyway?)

Thanks to anyone that can tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: I love it when I google for help and find my answer in a question that I forgot I even asked more than a year earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Vim/vim71/gvim.exe' --nofork '%*'"
```

Comment: Sir, you are the ant's pants.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

are you running msysgit? if so, try

```
git config --global core.editor '/c/Program Files/Vim/vim71/gvim.exe'
```

Comment: Nope.  Just a regular Git binary for Windows.  I tried it anyway, and Git was not amused.